# Android layouts - images for the different screen resolutions and the same density

Tags: android, image, performance, responsive-design, resize

I want to show some images on the background that is also image. Say my background image contains an empty squares, and I want to show an apple image that must appear exactly in one of that squares. 
I have a problems with the apple sizes, as the background scales and fits the screen, but apple image stays the same for the different resolution and the same density devices.

Say I have two ldpi devices with 240x320 and 480x800 resolutions. When I keep my drawable aple file in the drawable-ldpi folder, and use wrap_content for height and width (or fixed dp values) those 2 devices draw the apple with the same size, like it is described in the documentation.

The LinearLayout works slow when I stack them.
Using RelaytiveLayout I must programmatically resize the images which is also "not so good" solution I guess.

I've found a solution here https://github.com/intuit/sdp that maps the dp-s.

They set dimen-s for values-sw300dp to be

```
<dimen name="_10sdp">10.00dp</dimen>
```

and for values-sw480dp to be

```
<dimen name="_10sdp">16.00dp</dimen>
```

and so on for the different cases ...

So when I set the with of the apple to be _10sdp it means different dp-s for my 2 devices with the same density and solves my problem. Is it a good solution as it seems to be for me?
Is there any other easy ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the recommended solution as you could see in the [iosched github repository](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/res) which is a generally good source of knowing whether something is a desired common practice at least according to Google since i know they spend a lot of time to create this code to reflect the best practices and obtain the new APIs

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems good, just as common solution, would be good to use folders described in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers). 
For your case, as easier solution I would suggest to not use an apple image separately and place it in background's square. You can have an image: apple in square, and place it on background wherever you want. An apple will always be in a square and you can avoid tiresome process of creating dimens for each configuration.

Comment: The apple in the background will be deformed on some screens while it will look ok on other screens. The square in my background will become rectangle and loose its bounds, which is unacceptable for the apple. The second reason no to keep the apple in the background is that I have many fruits, so I have to keep many background images in that case.
Thanks a lot.